# Zoo Component Migration from Joomla 1.5 to 3

Tags: json, xml, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla1.5

I am using [Zoo Component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/zoo) in Joomla 1.5 and downloaded (export) data from Zoo component which is in XML format. Now, New version of Zoo component allow only JSON and CSV format to import data.

So, how to migrate Zoo component data to new version?

I have tried using online conversion tool which convert XML to JSON but not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit mean of Zoo to switch the format and not allow importing XML... but there's 2 ways around it.

1st - You can simply upgrade the version of Zoo on your old website, it should preserve all of the data. Zoo v2.5 or v2.6 is when they switched over from XML to JSON. From the Zoo v2.6 you will be able to export CSV or JSON.

- Note: if you have an old version of ZOO (like v2.3 or less) first upgrade to v2.4, then to v2.6.

Old versions are available [here](http://yootheme.com/zoo/downloads), click **Archieve** in the corner.

2nd - If you don't want to risk doing anything to a site in production, you can convert the XML to JSON is a slightly haphazard way:

- On a localhost or separate folder/server create a clean installation of Joomla 1.5 and install Zoo v2.4
- Import your XML data into there (you might need to remake the types, not sure how to automatically)
- Upgrade you Zoo to v2.6 - then you will be able to export JSON from there

More info on the nuances of upgrading zoo [here](http://yootheme.com/support/question/31793)